# Java Threading Model

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

I have a question on normal java threading theory.

Thread A has taken a lock on some object, let say xObj.  Now how does Thread B know that Thread A has already taken a lock on object xObj.

How this has been implemented in java.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for your answers....Here i would like to clear that...I don't have to implement this.My concern is How Java has implemented that.How Thread B will get to know that someone has already taken a lock on Object.May be Object class or some other class has implemented this.

Comment: By `taken a lock` you mean `capture monitor of object`? If yes, answer on your question may be found in the native code of JVM only.

Comment: synchronized(xObj) { ----------------------- } Thread A has taken a lock on xObj.If Thread B comes, how it will get to know that Thread A has already taken a lock and thread B will wait until Thread A release the lock on xObj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thread A has taken a lock on some object, let say xObj. Now how does Thread B know that Thread A has already taken a lock on object xObj.

It depends on the kind of lock you are talking about.

- For a primitive mutex, one thread cannot test if another thread holds the mutex, let alone find out which thread it is.  (It can test if holds the lock however ...)
- The `Lock` interface similarly doesn't support this.
- The `ReentrantLock` class *does* provide a method to find this out: see `ReentrantLock.getOwner()`.  Note however that this is a `protected` method, so you'd need to create a subclass of `ReentrantLock` if you wanted to make the method generally available.

---

I would also question the value of such a method.  It can only tell you which (if any) thread owns the lock at the instant that the call was made.  An instant later, the owner could have changed.

By constrast, `Thread.holdsLock()` gives you information that you can rely on ... albeit that it is information that isn't useful under most circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You have below options

1. [Thread.holdsLock(Object object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock%28java.lang.Object%29) in this case you will need thread instance of B in A.
2. [ReentrantLock.getOwner()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#getOwner%28%29), [ReentrantLock.hasQueuedThread(Thread thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#hasQueuedThread%28java.lang.Thread%29)

> But there is no need that B should know that A has the lock , once lock is released it will be available for B to use if there aren't any threads waiting on it.

Answer (score 0):

Which lock are you talking about? If it is a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) for instance, you can just call

```
 lock.getOwner()
```

Edit:

```
synchronized(xObj) { }
```

Is not a lock as you are implying. It is conceptually closer to a [monitor lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29). You have limited functionality
using synchronized blocks, and that's exactly why classes like ReentrantLock exists.From the doc

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

Comment: synchronized(xObj)
{
-----------------------   
} Thread A has taken a lock on xObj.If Thread B comes, how it will get to know that Thread A has already taken a lock and thread B will wait until Thread A release the lock on xObj.

Answer (score 0):

**-** When a thread gets the `lock` of an object, then all the `synchronized` methods can only be accessed through **that thread and none**, till it leaves the lock.

**-** If `Thread A` has the `lock` of an object and `Thread B` tries to access the lock on the **same object**, it `can't access` it. As the lock is with A, **its Not important for Thread B ,that lock is with whom, but is the lock available**. If not Thread B moves into blocked state till the lock is released by Thread A.

Comment: How thread B will get to know that someone ( you are correct, its not important for B, that lock is with whom) has already taken a lock.This is my question.

Comment: @VJS, fine it you are using the ReentrantLock then you can try this ReentrantLock.getOwner().